# how to select and automatically click on the particular link on the basis of its id/name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts

Sir,

In my project , there are saveral days where users are creating it by clicking on "add day button"
and on the particular days they are adding exercises on it.
Once they are clicking on that day , its all data are showing.
And When users click on the "add this exercise in this day"  button ,then automatically that particular day link should click..How can i do this?

Note: Am using struts2 and jquery div and targets.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

When you attach an event handler you can use this to check which button is clicked

```
$('div').click(function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

and than you can do actions based on the id

Comment: my problem is like this::: #1. i clicks on a day and its data is showing in its div.  #2. Now i have to add exercises on it,so i choose/select a exercise from my second div.  #3. Then am going to add this exercise on that Day. MY PROBLEM ARISES HERE: when i click on the "add button" then that particular clicked "day"button  is collapsing. i want to click on that button link dynamically.    PLEASE PROVIDE ME SOLUTION ACCORDING TO THIS SITUATION.

Comment: @user1268313 without seeing your code it's really difficult to help you

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a click event you just call the click method, without parameters.

```
$('div').click();
```

Comment: i have a "add this exercise on the selected Day" button.

Comment: my problem is like this::: #1. i clicks on a day and its data is showing in its div.  #2. Now i have to add exercises on it,so i choose/select a exercise from my second div.  #3. Then am going to add this exercise on that Day. MY PROBLEM ARISES HERE: when i click on the "add button" then that particular clicked "day"button  is collapsing. i want to click on that button link dynamically.    PLEASE PROVIDE ME SOLUTION ACCORDING TO THIS SITUATION.